# laravel how to convert variable to string in the render function

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am working on a laravel project, i am trying to load my datatable, i wanna i have a column used for sending a post request, here is my script:

```
var datatable = $('#table').on('xhr.dt', function(e, settings, json, xhr) {
            $("#loadingAnimation").hide();
        }).DataTable({
ajax: {
                url: "/xxxxxxxxx",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
            },
 columns: [
                
                {
                    data: 'id',
                    name: 'id',
                },
{
                    data: null, 
                    "render":function(row, type, val, meta){
                            return `
                            <form method="post" action="/xx/yyy/"+${row[`id`]}>
                            @csrf
                            <button>send</button>
                            </form>
                            `;
                            return '';
                    },
                    "orderable": false
                },
]
});
```

so in the render part, I wanna i can call the route(/xx/yyy/{id}), i tried to call "/xx/yyy/1" and it worked, but when i wanna tried to use the variable row[id] it cannot work, can you please help me to figure it out? Many THX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is correct way of adding parameters in blade

```
<form method="post" action="/xx/yyy/{{$row['id']}}"> 

Then form here
</form>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your kind help, i tried in this way, and i got a log error :undefined constant row, and I tried this: action="/xx/yyy/${row['id']}" and it worked, but still thanks for your solution.

Comment: Yes `$` symbol is missing ... i updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is JavaScript right? If so then I think you should use:

```
return '
<form method="post" action="/xx/yyy/'+ row["id"] +'">
@csrf
<button>send</button>
</form>
';
```

If it is JavaScript you should not have to use $ and {} for passing the variable and also the variable was outside the "" meaning that it was not added to the value of the action attribute.

Comment: thanks for your solution, i finall tried this: action="/xx/yyy/${row['id']}" and it worked, but still thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Your combining a Blade Directives (@csrf) with Javascript. For this to work the script has to be part on the blade template page (not external). I don't know if you're doing this since little code is given.